# devise_for :users error in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have this problem with a recent migration from a Rails 3 app to 4. I have not seeing this error on other applications I upgraded.

When starting the server I get this error. I realised the error appears while the `devise_for :users` route is present on `routes.rb`.

Any idea what is causing this error and how to fix it?

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007fc453039b10 @paths=["/Users/user/Sites/mysite/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fc4531562a0>]> (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/user/Sites/mysite/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/user/Sites/mysite/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/user/Sites/mysite/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/user/Sites/mysite/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@mysite/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what version of devise are you using?

Comment: the version is devise 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same error was reported here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10559

The solution for me was to update to latest edge rails (4.0.10.beta) that fix the delegate issue that was preventing to show the real error when launching the server.

That helped me debug the code better and fix each individual error due to the migration.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is probably your problem: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10559

Suggestions:

1. Remove the attr_accessible in each of your model
2. Add the protected_attributes gem